# How put increment name variable in loop

Tags: php

I'm not a programmer, but I have to do some work with my site.

Please tell me how to do it

Question in the comment code.

```
<?php
 for ($o = 1; $o < 9 ; $o++) {
$file = '/patch/to/file_'.$o.'.xml';

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load($file);
 $destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("model");
 foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {

            ${'czy' . $o}[] = $child->textContent;
          }
      }
   }

}


$merge = array_merge($czy1, $czy2, $czy3, $czy4, $czy5, $czy6, $czy7, $czy8);
// How do this?? but in loop function (from $czy1 to $czy8)?
```

Comment: Hint: `array_merge(array_merge($czy1, $czy2), $c3)` equals `array_merge($czy1, $czy2, $c3)`.

Comment: Thanks for your Hint but I still I don't now how do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for ($o = 1; $o < 9 ; $o++) {
$file = '/patch/to/file_'.$o.'.xml';

 $result = [];

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load($file);
 $destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("model");
 foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {

            $result = array_merge($result, $child->textContent);
          }
      }
   }
```

See what my hint meant now?